# Importing .nt file to MYSQL with rdfproc on ubuntu

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, rdf

I am trying to import and .nt file to my mysql as downloaded from [dbpedia](http://wiki.dbpedia.org/Downloads38#dbpedia-ontology).
I am using ubuntu server so I run following commands to install rdfproc

- apt-get update
- apt-get install redland-utils

Now, to import the file I am running following command:

```
rdfproc -n -s mysql -t "host='localhost',database='wikicats',user='root',password='abcd'" dbpedia parse category_labels_en.nt ntriples
```

But, I am getting following error:

```
rdfproc: invalid argument `mysql' for `-s / --storage'
```

So I checked the available storage with command

```
rdfproc --storage help
```

And I got the following output:

```
hashes      Indexed hashes
trees       Balanced trees
memory      In memory lists
file        Local file based store
uri         URI store (read-only)
```

Please suggest what should I do to complete this .nt file import to mysql DB?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It means that Redland has been compiled without MySQL support.

The [documentation](http://librdf.org/docs/api/redland-storage-module-mysql.html) states that it's compiled only when MySQL 3 or 4 are available. It doesn't say anything about MySQL 5.